# Set the interval in data-uk-timepicker

Tags: javascript, uikit

I am using a [`data-uk-timepicker`](http://getuikit.com/docs/timepicker.html) in my website.

I want to set the interval for 5 minutes but it always takes the default interval i.e. 30 minutes. How can i set an arbitrary interval?

Comment: what is `data-uk-timepicker`?

Comment: @Grundy i believe he is talking about [UIKit's time picker](http://getuikit.com/docs/timepicker.html). OP, What have you tried so far, can you post some code or fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

if @Seçkin is right, so you can't change this. You can [see source](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/master/src/js/components/timepicker.js#L150) and find line

```
times['24h'].push({value: (h+':00')});
times['24h'].push({value: (h+':30')});
```

where this times hardcoded.

Comment: Very nice investigation. @apache, Of course you could go ahead and fork the repo to add an arbitrary interval feature, you'd be doing good for the world, eh?

Answer (score 1):

Add below code on your timepicker js  file

> times['24h'].push({value: (h+':00')});
>   times['24h'].push({value: (h+':05')});times['24h'].push({value: (h+':10')}); 
>   .... 
>   times['24h'].push({value: (h+':55')});

Comment: times['24h'].push({value: (h+':00')});
times['24h'].push({value: (h+':05')});
times['24h'].push({value: (h+':10')});
times['24h'].push({value: (h+':15')});
....
....
times['24h'].push({value: (h+':55')});